# Mistake in code but I cant find it javascript html css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a navbar where the active site ist shown
html and js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title>ANKAR - Website Version</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <nav>
            <h4 class="logo">ANKAR</h4>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">
                <div class="line_1"></div>
                <div class="line_2"></div>
                <div class="line_3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="front_page">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>ANKAR</h1>
            <p>Where do you want to go, Pawel?</p>
            <div class="cta">
                <button class="star_wars">Star Wars</button>
                <button class="ld">Lucid Dreaming</button>
                <button class="ba">Add pls</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
    <script src="../static/java_file.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "nav ul li a.active" ).bind( "click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var clickedItem = $( this );
                $( "nav ul li a.active" ).each( function() {
                    $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
                });
                clickedItem.addClass( "active" );
            });
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

there is some kind of mistake here because it does not work. I cant do js thats why i copied a code and changed the "nav ul li a.active" things nothing more. I dont know where the mistake is. Pls help
CSS:

```
nav ul li a.active::after {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, grey 30%, #fff 0%, #fff 80%);
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    box-shadow:  15px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,255,255,1);
    clip-path: inset(-10px -0.5px -10px 2px);
}
```

Comment: A good place to start is to check your console for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the click to only happen on 'active' elements.  Change that block so it is attached to all nav links, not just the 'active' one(s):

```
           $( "nav ul li a" ).bind( "click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var clickedItem = $( this );
                $( "nav ul li a.active" ).each( function() {
                    $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
                });
                clickedItem.addClass( "active" );
            });
```

Comment: This code won't run as is, as he hasn't imported jquery anywhere.

Comment: @Laif - indeed!

Answer (score 1):

This script uses jQuery, a library for javascript

Include this at the top of your `<head>` if you want it to work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @Wyrden if you want us to help you you need to be a lot more specific than "doesn't work", we don't work for you.

Comment: ok sry: the navbar <a> elements do not light up if I click on them only the class="active" does because it is set on it in the css code. So, the function does not work because if I click on an <a> element it should get the class="active" and light up

Comment: @Wyrden learn jquery/javascript, this problem is just a result of you copy and pasting code. As a hint, the error lies here: `$( "nav ul li a.active" ).bind`, this is where you bind the function to specific elements, and right now it's binding to a tags with the active class.

Comment: so what should i do how can i bind it do I have to add a class

Comment: @Wyrden someone else answered the question demonstrating how to do this.